# How to set email header X-Type with Django EmailMessage

Tags: django, email

I need to set X-Type header for email, which sends with Django 1.4. I use default EmailMessage class from Django.
Would work something like this?

```
email = EmailMessage(title, body, sender, recipient,
            headers = {'X-Type': 'my x-type header'})
```

Or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: of course, it would work.
Note: for some mailing services extra headers may need to  be converted to json.